# Return type of count() versus count(fieldName)

Tags: apex, soql

The following code works

```
Integer i = [select count() from Account];
System.debug(i);
```

But the code below results in and error: "Illegal assignment from LIST to Integer LINE: 1 COLUMN: 1"

```
Integer i = [select count(Id) from Account];
System.debug(i);
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

COUNT() is an older SOQL function that was available prior to other aggregate functions. It returns an integer. If you use COUNT(fieldName) the result of the query will be a List instead.

COUNT() is equivalent to COUNT(*) in SQL. It return the total row count. COUNT(fieldName) only counts the number of non-null records. If you want to use COUNT(fieldName), the following code should work:

```
List<AggregateResult> result  = [select count(Id) total from Account];
System.debug(result[0].get('total'));
```

For more about the difference between COUNT() and COUNT(fieldName) take a look at the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm).

Answer (score 0):

**COUNT()** returns the number of items in a group, including NULL values and duplicates.

**COUNT(expression)** evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of non null values.